# Having trouble removing part of a string

Tags: php

Given the string "123456789@test.com", I'm trying to remove from the '@' symbol on, I just want the numbers. I've been trying to split the string into an array and remove array elements based on if that element is numeric, then merging the elements back into a string. My code...

```
$employee_id = "123456789@test.com";
$employee_id_array = str_split($employee_id);

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($employee_id_array); $i++) {
    if(is_numeric($employee_id_array[$i]) === false) {
        unset($employee_id_array[$i]);
        $employee_id_array = array_values($employee_id_array);
    }
}

$employee_id = implode($employee_id_array);

echo "employee id: $employee_id";
```

What it should print out: 123456789

What it actually prints out: 123456789ts.o

What am I missing?

Comment: Notice how once it hits the non-numeric part, it deletes every other character. That should clue you in. But really just `explode("@",$employee_id)[0]` to get the number.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Thanks for the solution! Just out of curiosity, why is it deleting every other character?

Comment: Because you keep changing the array as you're iterating through it. So when you delete character 4, the character that was character 5 is now character 4 and gets skipped by your loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo strstr($employee_id, '@', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all the numbers in `employee_id` string:

```
$employee_id = "123456789@test.com";
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $employee_id, $matches);
echo $matches[0][0];
```

This will return all the numbers in the provided string.

If you want to get string before @ in `employee_id` then you can try this:

```
$employee_id = "123456789@test.com";
$output = explode('@', $employee_id);
echo $output[0];
```